# python docx: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'add_paragraph'

Tags: python

just started learning python, now I need help with the python docx function.
I'm using python v3.5.1

That's the code I'd like to run from a .py file:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('I am adding a new paragraph here.')
document.save('test-thu18feb-b.docx')
```

After pressing F5, I get this message in the python shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Schauer/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/docx-
test-thu18feb-a.py", line 4, in <module>
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('I am adding a new paragraph here.')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'add_paragraph'
```

Thanks a lot for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
document = Document
```

assigns [the function `docx.Document`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/docx/api.html#Document) to `document`.

```
document = Document()
```

assigns *the value returned* by the function `docx.Document` to `document`. You need the latter.

---

`docx.Document` is a [constructor function](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/document.html#document-constructor). It returns instances of the `docx.document.Document` class.

---

Per [the docs](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/docx/api.html#Document), this is the definition of the `docx.Document` function:

```
def Document(docx=None):
    """
    Return a |Document| object loaded from *docx*, where *docx* can be
    either a path to a ``.docx`` file (a string) or a file-like object. If
    *docx* is missing or ``None``, the built-in default document "template"
    is loaded.
    """
    docx = _default_docx_path() if docx is None else docx
    document_part = Package.open(docx).main_document_part
    if document_part.content_type != CT.WML_DOCUMENT_MAIN:
        tmpl = "file '%s' is not a Word file, content type is '%s'"
        raise ValueError(tmpl % (docx, document_part.content_type))
    return document_part.document
```

So `docx.Document` is a function, but `docx.document.Document` is a class.
Since you import

```
from docx import Document
```

`Document` refers to `docx.Document` in your code.

Comment: Document doesn't seems like a function. Its returns a instance of the class Document.